# Can there be an if condition inside the Hibernate Create Criteria?

Tags: hibernate, groovy, createcriteria

I am using `HibernateCriteriaBuilder` api to write my Criteria Queries. I want to know if inside `Criteria` we can have conditional logic, such as an `if` statement?

For example:

```
 OnemonthList=it.createCriteria().list {   
   if (res_id!='all'){
        eq('graresource',resourceInstance)
   }         
    between('currentdate', fromDate, toDate)         
    projections {       
    trans {
      countDistinct('id')    
    }
    groupProperty('currentdate')
        }                  
    }
```

Is this valid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use any sort of conditional or looping logic inside of the criteria DSL. Your example will work. Using loops can be incredibly useful, for example:

```
Domain.createCriteria().list {
    params.mapOfConditions.each {
        eq it.key, it.val
    }
}
```

will dynamically add an `eq` for each entry in the map that you have.